# Get Coordinates for array of Addresses

Tags: swift

I'm parsing an an XML file which gives me an array of `ParkingGarage`.

```
struct ParkGarage: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var link: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
    var pubDate: String = ""
    var guid: String = ""
    var dcDate: String = ""
    var state: String = ""
    var freeSpaces: Int = 0
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
}
```

My problem is, that I  have to get the `coordinates` of each garage after it has been parsed since I'm not getting that information of the XML.

This is my `loadData` function:

```
func loadData() {
        lazy var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        var invalid: Bool = false
        let xmlParser = GarageParser()
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.my-url") else {
            print("Your API end point is Invalid")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
            var fetchedGarages = xmlParser.parseGarages(data: data)
            
            fetchedGarages = self.setAllNewFields(garages: fetchedGarages)
            
            for (index, garage) in fetchedGarages.enumerated() {
                geocoder.geocodeAddressString(garage.address + ", Zürich") { placemarks, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            invalid = true
                        }
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    
                    guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard let lat = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude else{return}
                    
                    guard let lon = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude else{return}
                    
                    let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
                    
                    fetchedGarages[index].coordinate = coords
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.garages = fetchedGarages
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```

My Problem now is, that it is not awaited until all coordinates are fetched.

Is there a good way to do so?

I'm new to swift, I'm happy for all the input I can get.

Comment: You need to use a `DispatchQueue` for that, with `enter()`, `leave()` and `notify()`.

Comment: Thank you! I looked into it and it makes a lot more sense now!